# Trade city on a lagoon?

Tags: geography

Is it possible to have a major trade city built on the edges of a lagoon?

For a city I'm designing it is situated on a lagoon but if there is a small strait/canal so that ships can move in and out of the lagoon does it still qualify as a lagoon?

I ask not only for geographic understanding but also because the name of the city means lagoon.

Comment: For examples in fantasy, see: Braavos, Camorr

Comment: In terms of the geography a lagoon is only a _lagoon_, as opposed to the more general [estuary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estuary) or a [fjord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fjord) or a barred coast if it _does_ have a single point where the ocean has access and there is a general circulation of seawater, at least with each tide but often continuously.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A good example would be the city of [Venice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venice), which is built on the [Venetian Lagoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venetian_Lagoon).

This is, in fact, [where the name lagoon comes from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagoon#Etymology).

Historically, from the 9th to the 12th century, the city was a hub of trade between Western Europe and the Byzantine Empire and the Islamic world.

So clearly it's possible to have a major trade city on a lagoon, the name itself comes from a real world example.

Comment: I actually wasnt aware Venice was on a Lagoon. I assumed it was an archipelago in the middle of the Adriatic. Thanks!

Comment: Besides this, and Lagos mentioned below, Kaliningrad and Szczeczin on the Baltic are also notable examples.

Answer (score 6):

Lagos, Nigeria
It is situated on a lagoon and its Yoruba name, Eko, means lake or lagoon.

Comment: You might add to your answer that Lagos has been a typical trade city from the 15th century, as a hub fore, amongst other things, palm oil trade and, when colonized, trans-Atlantic slave trade.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa I believe it's a simple answer for a simple question. No need to elaborate.